# Buddypress custom activity loop and query function

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, buddypress

I added an additional activity feed to my profile page that queries for a linked user and returns their activity. The problem is, I want to write this over to a function as there will often be other areas of the site that need to use this same query.

Here is the user query. It's just a comparison query to find and return the linked user's ID.

```
    global $bp, $wpdb;
    $myid = $bp->loggedin_user->id;
    $ourlink = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'linkid' AND user_id = '$myid'");
    $partnerid = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT user_id from $wpdb->usermeta where meta_key='linkid' AND meta_value = '$ourlink' AND user_id != '$myid'");
    $partner =  '&user_id=' . $partnerid;
```

Which is then used in the activity loop.

```
<?php if ( bp_has_activities( bp_ajax_querystring( 'activity' ) . $partner ) ) : ?>
```

However, rewriting this as a function and then calling that function right before the loop, though it will still return the ID, it no longer works for the sake of the activity loop.

Function: (in WP functions.php file)

```
function sw_partner_id() {

    global $bp, $wpdb;
    $myid = $bp->loggedin_user->id;
    $ourlink = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'linkid' AND user_id = '$myid'");
    $partnerid = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT user_id from $wpdb->usermeta where meta_key='linkid' AND meta_value = '$ourlink' AND user_id != '$myid'");
    $partner =  '&user_id=' . $partnerid;

    return $partner;
}
```

Calling the function before the activity loop

```
<?php sw_partner_id(); ?>
<?php if ( bp_has_activities( bp_ajax_querystring( 'activity' ) . $partner ) ) : ?>
```

Error Update:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a function inside your functions.php file use hooks.Please notice **`global bp`** in your code since you forgot to add a $ sign.

Example:

```
function sw_partner_id() {

    global $bp, $wpdb;
    $myid = $bp->loggedin_user->id;
    $ourlink = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'linkid' AND user_id = '$myid'");
    $partnerid = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT user_id from $wpdb->usermeta where meta_key='linkid' AND meta_value = '$ourlink' AND user_id != '$myid'");
    $partner =  '&user_id=' . $partnerid;

        return $partner;
    }
//sample hook
add_action('admin_init','sw_partner_id');
```

After that try calling the function.
I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I've also tried going that route with no success either.

Comment: @Charles I have update my answer please notice 'global $bp'. And also if your in development mode try to change wp-config debug to true, so that you can see errors.

Comment: The missing $ was just a pasting error. Debug is kicking out undefined variable on the activity loop line.

Comment: Updated with some of the error. Not sure if it helps.